# How can I block remove or stop anonymous functions in jquery with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

How can block the following jquery function.
I've test different scripts and own scripts but noting works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        return "\
Are you sure you want to leave this page....";
  });
});
```

#

Sorry but both scripts don't stop the leave dialog

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Test
// @namespace      
// @description    Disable - remove the annoying onbeforeunload event
// @include        *
// @author         test
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
      unsafeWindow.onbeforeunload = null;

      unsafeWindow.onunload = null;

      //unsafeWindow.alert = null;

      //unsafeWindow.confirm = null;

      //unsafeWindow.prompt = null;

      //unsafeWindow.open = null;

      //$(window).off('beforeunload'); //don't work
$(window).on('beforeunload',function() {/* override function that does nothing*/});
})();
```

Comment: Not 100% sure this would work, but you might be able to override it with a different function, ie `$(window).on('beforeunload',function() {/* override function that does nothing*/});`

Comment: @Bucky24 Nope, jQuery allows you to keep attaching more and more event handlers, so this doesn't overwrite what's already there. You might be able to do it with plain javascript with `window.beforeunload = null;` or something like that, but I don't know if that works across the board.

Comment: @JoeEnos oh good to know, I was unaware of that.

Comment: @alletandere Is it possible that the greasemonkey script is running prior to the script that assigns the event? You'd have to make sure this runs after the `on('beforeunload')` script is called - you might be able to just put it in `jQuery(document).ready` - if your greasemonkey script still runs first, maybe set a timeout, like `setTimeout(3000, function() { $(window).off('beforeunload'); });`, to ensure it fires well after the event is first assigned, but early enough so it fires prior to the user trying to leave the page.

Answer (score 4):

I believe [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is what you're looking for:

```
$(window).off('beforeunload');
```